# How can I pull non-default properties from active directory using get-adgroupmember

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

When I run:

get-adgroup -filter {displayname -eq 'groupname'} | get-adgroupmember | format-table name, surname, givenname, officephone

The only field that returns is a default property "name". The rest show blank.

Comment: I know you said Powershell, but does it need to be PS?  Would a gui tool suffice?

Comment: TheCleaner - There's a lot of red tape with getting software approved for use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really like one-liners:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {displayName -eq 'groupName'} | Get-ADGroupMember |Foreach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $($_.SID) -Properties name,sn,givenName,otherTelephone} | Format-Table name,sn,givenName,otherTelephone
```

If you want to manipulate the User objects further, you might want to store them in an array:

```
$Group   = Get-ADGroup -Filter {displayName -eq 'groupName'}
$Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group
$Users = @()
Foreach-Object -InputObject $Members -Process {$Users += (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SID -Properties *)}

$Users | Format-Table name,sn,givenName,otherTelephone
```

Comment: Mathias, I replaced the foreach alias (%) with the actual CmdLet. We want to make code as readable as possible, also for PowerShell beginners.

Comment: @Trondh Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Properties` parameter you can specify to retrieve extended properties.  Here's some examples from the [TechNet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617196.aspx):

```
# Retrieve and display the list of all the properties for an ADGroup object
Get-ADGroup -Identity Administrators -Properties *| Get-Member

# To retrieve the extended properties "OfficePhone" and "Organization" and 
# the default properties of an ADUser object named "SaraDavis"
GetADUser -Identity SaraDavis -Properties OfficePhone,Organization

# To retrieve the properties with LDAP display names of "otherTelephone" and 
# "otherMobile", in addition to the default properties for the same user 
GetADUser -Identity SaraDavis -Properties otherTelephone,otherMobile | Get-Member
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind I would recommend you a tool.

---

...

I am using 'AD-Info' from 'Cjwdev Software' to pull out Information from Active Directory.
In my case the Standard Edition is actively being used to analyze the AD and generating customized reports.
In your case the free version should probably do it already.

Answer (score -1):

If you run

```
get-adgroup  -filter {displayname -eq 'Consultants'} |get-adgroupmember | format-list *
```

You'll see that there aren't a lot of fields/properties available in the first place; the ones you want aren't there.

```
distinguishedName : CN=buncha junk,DC=net
name              : User's name
objectClass       : user
objectGUID        : some guid
SamAccountName    : SAM account name
SID               : some SID
PropertyNames     : {distinguishedName, name, objectClass, objectGUID...}
PropertyCount     : 6
```

So, you can't do what you want with the tool you're using. You could probably pass the SID or the DN to another tool.

Comment: I don't mind doing it in two commands. Currently, I can store the list of users with:

get-adgroup -f {displayname -eq 'groupname'} | get-adgroupmember | select-object samaccountname

Comment: Sure - but the answer to the question, *as you asked it*, is that you can't. The cmdlet can't return what you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer. Makes sense now.